# VS2017 Web Publish Preview - unable to exclude files

Tags: visual-studio-2017, web-publishing

When publishing a web application in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise I can do a preview on the files that are changed by clicking the preview link.  The window comes up and I can uncheck files I dont want BUT, there is only a cancel button, and I am not able to update the file list.

[image]

There use to be the ability to click Publish from that view to only update the selected files but now that is no longer the case.

Is there an alternative "tools" way in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise to publish and exclude certain files from being updated for example the web.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an alternative tool however according to the forums this has been patched and will be deployed in the next public release (15.3).

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26373/publish-preview-not-allowing-selective-publish-of.html

I've been getting around this by copying the files that I don't want and replacing them back after I publish.

Comment: Yes I saw that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this has now been fixed as of the latest update 15.3 which was released this week